# Android - Mute or pause all existed audio streams when phone rings

Tags: android, audio-streaming

I have an Android application which uses audio streams. When the activity is created I set `setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);`. When the phone rings I want to mute all existed streams. To do this I tried to add a listener to `TelephonyManager` but I couldn't mute any stream. Below is my code:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
switch (phoneCallState) {
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, AudioManager.ADJUST_UNMUTE, 0);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,  AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
        break;
    default:
        Log.i(TAG, "onCallStateChanged: UNKNOWN_STATE: " + phoneCallState);
        break;
}
```

I want to have the same behavior as, for example, when I listen music and phone rings the media player is put on pause. I mention that the audio streams are managed by an external library so I do not have access to them.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how it should be done.
You should obtain `AudioManager`:

```
AudioManager = audioManager = (AudioManager) service.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Request audio focus using:

```
android.media.AudioManager#requestAudioFocus
```

The first parameter is the [`AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener.html#onAudioFocusChange(int)). It has one method to be overriden:

[`android.media.AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener#onAudioFocusChange`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener.html#onAudioFocusChange(int))

It's argument is `focusChange` and can be one of the following values:

- [AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)
- [AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT)
- [AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS)
- [AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK)

What you are interested in is AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS.

If the audio stream from the library is not respecting loosing of focus, then it is badly designed.

Comment: Ok, and what should I do in `OnAudioFocusChangeListener#onAudioFocusChange` method?

Comment: When audio focus loss occurred, mute AudioManager.

Comment: what stream? `AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL`?

Comment: Choose it by trial and error method. It depends on the library you used.